# Conway's Game of Life in Python generates random long lines in what should be dead zones

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, console, conways-game-of-life, cellular-automata

Decided to try my hand at implementing Conway's Game of Life in Python. Wasn't going for a particularly efficient implementation or anything, just wanted something that works. My board is a 2 dimensional list, each cell has a 1 or 0 to denote alive/dead. I'm randomly generating seeds right now; I'll work on feeding in seeds later.

My full code is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/LevBernstein/simpleConwayLife/blob/main/conway.py).

The problem is, my Game of Life sometimes generates long lines of alive cells in places that should just be dead.

Example:
[Looking normal so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xiZ4.png), but then, the very next generation, [sudden long line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68ziO.png).

Here's the code where I check for alive cells (far from optimal and could be improved with mod, I know):

```
def alive(board, y, x):
    neighbors = 0
    left = x - 1 if x > 0 else 9
    right = x + 1 if x < 9 else 0
    up = y - 1 if y > 0 else 9
    down = y + 1 if y < 9 else 0
    neighbors += board[up][left] + board[y][left] + board[down][left] + board[up][x] + board[down][x] + board[up][right] + board[y][right] + board[down][right]
    return 1 if (board[y][x] == 0 and neighbors == 3) or (board[y][x] == 1 and (neighbors == 2 or neighbors == 3)) else 0
```

My logic makes sense to me, but I'm clearly missing something. I thought it might be due to running the main loop too quickly, but I tried increasing the sleep time, and that changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot that I switched from hardcoded width and height to variables; instead of 9, should be width-1 and height-1. Whoops.